# Use regex to get info from a specific text format

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a text that contains stuff like this :

```
(some text)
libncursesw5-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev;(some text)
libx32ncursesw5 depends on libc6-x32 (>= 2.16);(some text)
libx32ncurses5-dev depends on libncurses5-dev (= 5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1);(some text)
libx32ncursesw5-dev depends on libc6-dev-x32;(some text)
lib32tinfo-dev depends on lib32c-dev;(some text)
```

Here is a full example on one of the sentences :

```
dpkg: error processing package lib32tinfo5 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libncurses5-dev:amd64:
 libncurses5-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
    Package libc6-dev is not installed.
    Package libc-dev is not installed.
```

The whole text is divided in several paragraphs such as the one above, each paragraph contains one of those sentences.

I would like a regex using re library in python that would give me something like this using findall option :

```
('libc6-dev', '', 'libc-dev', '')
('libc6-x32','2.16')
('libncurses5-dev','5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1')
('libc6-dev-x32','')
('lib32c-dev','')
```

In another words, I would like your help in order to get from such text, a tuple containing the packages with their versions if specified.

I did this regex :

```
(?<=depends on )([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)(?: \([=> ]*([a-zA-Z0-9-+.]*)(?:\)))?|(?: \| )([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)(?: \([=> ]*([a-zA-Z0-9-+.]*)(?:\)))?(?=;)
```

I got this result :

```
('libc6-dev', '', '', '')
('', '', 'libc-dev', '')
('libc6-x32', '2.16', '', '')
('libncurses5-dev', '5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1', '', '')
('libc6-dev-x32', '', '', '')
('lib32c-dev', '', '', '')
```

As you can see, for the sentence :

```
libncursesw5-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev;
```

I got this answer :

```
('libc6-dev', '', '', '')
('', '', 'libc-dev', '')
```

Rather than this one :

```
('libc6-dev', '', 'libc-dev', '')
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

input = """(some text)
libncursesw5-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev;(some text)
libx32ncursesw5 depends on libc6-x32 (>= 2.16);(some text)
libx32ncurses5-dev depends on libncurses5-dev (= 5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1);(some text)
libx32ncursesw5-dev depends on libc6-dev-x32;(some text)
lib32tinfo-dev depends on lib32c-dev;(some text)"""

#a = []
#m = re.findall("depends on ([^\s;]+)\ \|\ ([^\s;]+)", input) # 1
#a = a + m
#m = re.findall("depends on ([^\s;]+)\ \([><=]{,2} ([^;]+)\)", input) # 2, 3
#a = a + m
#m = re.findall("depends on ([^\s;]+)", input) # 4, 5
#a = a + m

m = re.findall("depends on ([^\s;]+)\ \|\ ([^\s;]+)|depends on ([^\s;]+)\ \([><=]{,2} ([^;]+)\)|depends on ([^\s;]+)", input)

print m
```

output:

```
[
    ('libc6-dev', 'libc-dev', '', '', ''),
    ('', '', 'libc6-x32', '2.16', ''),
    ('', '', 'libncurses5-dev', '5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1', ''),
    ('', '', '', '', 'libc6-dev-x32'),
    ('', '', '', '', 'lib32c-dev')
]
```

you can get it one by one or all together with | i don't know if this can help you